# Java servlet count logged in users

Tags: java, gradle, servlets

I got stuck with an assignment in my course Web Engineering. We are learning about Servlets and are using Gradle.

One part of the assignment was to create a login form. When you login with a username it should create a session. So far so good.

The next part of the assignment was to count users that are logged in in a thread safe way. So I created a class Counter, which implements the interface HttpSessionListener and increments the amount of activeSessions when a session is created.

So what I expect to happen is when I login with user1 it should say activeSessions = 1 and when I login with a user2 it should say activeSessions = 2. It doesn't.

So I think my conception of sessions is wrong.

How do I get the number of users that are logged in?

Edit: In the assignment it says: *Create a class Counter which implements the interface HttpSessionListener which should count logged in users/users with an active session.*

**Login.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Navigation
 */
@WebServlet(urlPatterns ={ "/Login" })
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Login() {
        super();
    }



    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        int length = username.length();

        int sessions;


        if(length >= 3) {
            response.getWriter().append("Willkommen: " + username);

            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("username", username);
            sessions = Counter.getActiveSessions();

            response.getWriter().append("\n \n");
            response.getWriter().append("Session String: " + session.toString());

            response.getWriter().append("\n \n");
            response.getWriter().append("Session Attribut: " + session.getAttributeNames());

            response.getWriter().append("\n \n");
            response.getWriter().append("Username Zeichenanzahl: " + username.length());
            response.getWriter().append("\n \n");
            response.getWriter().append("Sessionanzahl: " + sessions);

            //RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("protected/index.html");
            //rd.forward(request, response);

        } else {
            response.sendError(401, "Zu kurzer Username, du Otto!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Counter.java**

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Counter implements HttpSessionListener {


    private static final AtomicInteger activeSessions = new AtomicInteger(0);

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        activeSessions.incrementAndGet();
    }


    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        activeSessions.decrementAndGet();
    }


    public static int getActiveSessions() {
        return activeSessions.get();
    }   


}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>&quot;HelloServlet&quot;</display-name>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>Counter</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Your code looks like it should work.  When you say it doesn't work, does the count just stay at zero or what happens?  You might want to add some debug logging to your `HttpSessionListener` to make sure it's getting called as you expect.

Comment: Actually it worked. I had to use different browsers ( beforehand I tried it with Chrome incognito mode)  to log in with multiple users. When I did that, it incremented the session count.